# Angular 6 with Angular Google Maps (AGM) - How to get all visible markers?

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-google-maps

I have a giant list of markers inside my map, and when I click in one of them it call a function to display the data of that marker.

What I'm trying to do is to show the info of all the markers that are visible in the viewport of the map, like this exemple:

https://jsfiddle.net/glafarge/mbuLw/

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<agm-map 
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [disableDefaultUI]="false"
  [zoomControl]="false">

  <agm-marker 
      *ngFor="let store of stores; let i = index"
      (markerClick)="markerClick(infoWindow, store)"
      [iconUrl]="customIcon"
      [latitude]="store.LATITUDE"
      [longitude]="store.LONGITUDE">

    <agm-info-window #infoWindow>
      <strong>info window</strong>
    </agm-info-window>

  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getStores();
}

getStores(): void {
    this.storesService.getStores()
      .subscribe(stores => {
        this.stores = stores.result;
      });
  }
```

I really don't know how to replicate the fiddle example since I'm not able to use the native events like getBounds() or marker.getPosition.